# Java Generics: Is there difference between List<E> and List<?>?

Tags: java, generics

Is there any difference between the following pieces of code?

```
public static <E> void printElements(List<E> list) {
    for (E elem : list) {
        System.out.println(elem);
    }
}
```

and

```
public static void printElements(List<?> list) {
    for (Object elem : list) {
        System.out.println(elem);
    }
}
```

If yes, can someone explain the difference and when to use what ?

Comment: This has been asked so many times... why don't you search the site for it?

Comment: Try invoking `list.add` and you'll notice the difference.

Comment: Just to be fair, neither of the "duplicates" actually is one. OP is asking about a difference subtler than those questions.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - Sort of. Effectively the OP is asking the wrong question - the answer to his question is "no" since he's only calling `toString()` which is defined in `Object` (which has little to do with the difference between `E` ans `?`). It would do the exact same thing without generics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference, although it's not intuitive. I recommend reading [the java standard tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) for more details.

Basically, the two are different and incompatible types. `List<E>` can store objects that extend, subclass, or actually are type `E`, but it's its own type. You cannot refer to a `List<String>` from a `List<Object>` reference, even though you can add a `String` to a `List<Object>`.

`List<?>` means that it's a list reference that can refer to any parameterized reference of it. A `List<?>` can refer to a `List<String>` or a `List<Integer>`. It's most useful when it's bounded by some interface or class. For example, the first method below (adapted from the java standard tutorial) will only take `List<Number>`, and not anything like `List<Double>` or `List<Integer>`.

```
public static double sumOfList(List<Number> list) {
    double s = 0.0;
    for (Number n : list)
        s += n.doubleValue();
    return s;
}
```

But the following code using wildcards can take `List<Double>` or `List<Integer>`. It's more flexible.

```
public static double sumOfList(List<? extends Number> list) {
    double s = 0.0;
    for (Number n : list)
        s += n.doubleValue();
    return s;
}
```

Comment: But `<T> double sumOfList(List<T> list)` will take a list with any type parameter, and that is what OP is asking about.

Comment: But then it is not typesafe. If you just say List<T>, then you  can pass it a List<String> and you might get a runtime exception based on what your method does. But a List<? extends Number> ensures the parameterized type is something your method can work with.

Comment: This difference is very difficult for me to understand, why `List<Number>` does not take `Double`s and `Integer`s if they are subtypes? I implemented an example by my own, where `Bmw` is a subclass of `Vehicle` and the following `List<Vehicle> list = new ArrayList<>()` can accept also `Bmw` types

Answer (score 0):

The first statement used a [Bounded Type Paramater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) `E`, whereas the 2nd statement uses a [Wildcard Parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html). The first statement is bounded as it "restrict the types that can be used as type arguments in a parameterized type". The `?`, in your case, says that it's a list of some type, but we don't know what it is. It's unbounded type.

Comment: It says the same in both cases. There is no bound for `E`, either.

Comment: For the example, yes. It only helps in compile-time checking as `E` gets bounded with a paramaterized type, when used. There is no way of bounding a `?` to a type.

Comment: I think you are confusing "bounding" with "binding".